# How do I write a select_tag statement so that it's multi line and easier to read?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line in my code:

```
      <%= f.select(:department_id , @departments.collect { |department| [ department.name, department.id ] }, {}, {class: "ui dropdown"} )%>
```

I'd love to break it into something like this:

```
      <%= f.select(
        :department_id , 
        @departments.collect do |department| 
          [ department.name, department.id ] 
        end, 
        {}, 
        {class: "ui dropdown"} 
      ) %>
```

But I keep getting different syntax errors. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a backslash for each line so ruby knows to interpret it as one line still?

```
   <%= f.select( \
    :department_id , \
    @departments.collect do |department| \
      [ department.name, department.id ] \
    end, \
    {}, \
    {class: "ui dropdown"} \
  ) %>
```

Comment: Yeah, @bkunzi01 I already did this. It was looking a bit . . . dirty. I'm hoping there's some cleaner way to go about this.